# Rails - using presenters in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, presenter

I am using Rails 4 to make an app. I use simple form for forms.

I am making presenters which display a slightly different label on form inputs.

I'm using them as follows:

In the form:

```
<%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => " <%= @project_presenter.description %> ", :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
```

In the presenter:

```
class ProjectPresenter

    def initialize(project, profile)
        @project = project
        @profile = user.profile
    end

    def description

        if student?
            "What does the project involve? "
        elsif sponsor?
            "Describe the project. "
        elsif educator?
            "What does the project involve? How will students be involved in the project? "
        elsif researcher?
            "What's involved in the project? Describe the issues to be addressed."
        end
    end
```

When I try this, I get a syntax error pointing at this line:

`<%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => " <%=` `@project_presenter.description %> ", :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>`

I think it doesn't want the <%= %> tags around the presenter.

How do you use presenters in forms?

Presenter is defined as:

```
class ProjectPresenter

    def initialize(project, profile)
        @project = project
        @profile = user.profile
    end

    def description
    ....
    end
```

Associations in the user model are:

```
  has_many :articles
  has_many :authentications, :dependent => :delete_all

  has_many :comments

  belongs_to :organisation
  has_one :profile
  has_many :qualifications
  has_many :identities

  has_many :trl_assessments, as: :addressable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

Comment: can you show the error and the stack trace that goes with it, also is your form (`f`) bound to the presenter or an activerecord model? consider using `<%= debug @project_presenter %>` and `<%= debug @project %>` before the form tag - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: and yes the label value should not be using erb tags, it is already in an erb block - these both should be valid: `<%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => @project_presenter.description, :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>` OR (not needed in this case but valid) 
`<%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => "#{@project_presenter.description}", :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with presenter, but one thing I can notice is that there is an error in your `description` method in the `Presenter` class: You are not closing your strings properly.

```
def description
  if student?
    "What does the project involve?"
  elsif sponsor?
    "Describe the project." 
  elsif educator?
    "What does the project involve? How will students be involved in the project? "
  elsif researcher?
    "What's involved in the project? Describe the issues to be addressed."
  end
end
```

Instead of what you presently have:

```
def description
  if student?
    "What does the project involve? 
  elsif sponsor?
    "Describe the project. 
  elsif educator?
    "What does the project involve? How will students be involved in the project? "
  elsif researcher?
    "What's involved in the project? Describe the issues to be addressed."
  end
end
```

Also, in your view:

```
<%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => " <%= @project_presenter.description %> ", :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
```

Since you are already calling `@project_presenter.description` in an `erb` tag, you don't need to specify another `<%= %>` here. If what you are trying to achieve here is String interpolation, all you have to do is call it as: `"#{@project_presenter.description}"`

```
<%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => "#{@project_presenter.description}", :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
```

And at the same time, I think you should be able to call `@project_presenter.description` directly without interpolation as follow:

```
<%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => @project_presenter.description, :input_html => {:rows => 10} %>
```

Comment: Hi Sunny, thanks for the spot. I actually deleted the bulk of the text from the actual presenter to take less space on this question and deleted the closing ". They are in the code.

Comment: What about the other use of interpolation I explained above?

Comment: I tried "#{@project_presenter.description}" - but I get a no method error. When I tried the 2nd suggestion, it prints the presenter reference as text

Comment: What is the `no_method` error? which method is it pointing to?

Comment: undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That means that `@project_presenter` is not defined

Comment: By the way, which presenter are you using?

Comment: presenter copied above

Comment: added associations from user model above